# PHP MySQL JSON: Error is: Token 'start of object' not expected after outer-most array or object

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've created a php which does a Select * on MySQL database to return data used in iOS App.  I'm unable to correctly parse the JSON, and am getting the error: "Token 'start of object' not expected after outer-most array or object" and also the error: "Garbage at end".  I'm a beginner in PHP, and wondering if someone could provide some insight?  Thank you!

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);

 $dbhost = "xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.com";

 $dbuser = "xxxxxxx";
 $dbpass = "xxxxxx";
 //database name
 $dbdb = "xxxxx";

 //connect to mySQL
 $connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
 or die ("connection error");

 //select database
 mysql_select_db($dbdb) or die ("database selection error"); // line 20

 //query the table android meal
 $query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM ScheduleDayOne");

 //create a while loop that places the returned data into an array
 while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

 //store the returned data into a variable
 $output = $list;

 //encode the returned data in JSON format
 echo json_encode($output);

 }
 //close connection
 mysql_close();

 ?>
```

Here is json output if I were to put in browser:

```
 {"id":"a1","session":"General","name":"Exhibitor Setup Begins","startTime":"0900","details":"9am Exhibitor Hall","png":"image","speaker1":"Johnson","speaker2":"Nelson","speaker3":"Kenner"}{"id":"b1","session":"General","name":"Conference Registration","startTime":"1000","details":"10am Noon Upper Level Lobby","png":"image","speaker1":"Jackson","speaker2":"Ward","speaker3":"Smith"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're echoing multiple objects without proper separation:

```
... son","speaker3":"Kenner"}{"id":"b1","session":"Ge ...
----------------------------^
```

You can wrap them into an array:

```
[{... son","speaker3":"Kenner"}, {"id":"b1","session":"Ge ...}]
^------------------------------^------------------------------^
```

**EDIT:**

To achieve this in PHP you could do this:

```
...
$output = array();

while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $output[] = $list;
}

echo json_encode($output);
...
```